# Implement ReadAll method using SerialPort

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am trying to implement `ReadAll` method using `SerialPort`, which will ensure it reads as many bytes as told to (I want to use this function for reading from serial port). Is this implementation correct way to go about this?

```
public static void ReadWholeArray (SerialPort sp, byte[] data)
{
    int offset=0;
    int remaining = data.Length; // ensure we read this many bytes
    while (remaining > 0)
    {
        int read = sp.Read(data, offset, remaining);
        if (read <= 0)
            throw new EndOfStreamException 
                (String.Format("End of data reached with {0} bytes left to read", remaining));
        remaining -= read;
        offset += read;
    }
}
```

**PS. Is there necessity for similar `WriteAll` method? (or does Write ensure to write as many bytes it was told to?).**

Comment: Why bother having `remaining` at all? Just keep `offset` and use `data.Length - offset` where you need to (and check for `while (offset < data.Length)`). Or keep `remaining` and ditch `offset`, of course. Not that either of these will changes will make a difference. Given that you've already got code that you believe works, I think this question would be better on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Actually this code I based from similar code you have (on your site) for reading streams (you think this doesn't work in this case?). I don't believe it works or not, I don't know if this is correct approach for Serial ports, this is why I asked. And also I asked question about write

Comment: Well I'd say the question about Write is really a different question, for another post - but you don't need to worry about it. The code looks fine to me - I'm not sure why you say "you think this doesn't work in this case?"

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes, sorry I misread your comment. You think read is fine even for serial ports. What should I do about Write? Have a similar WriteAll method?

Comment: No, as I said before, you don't need to worry about it - although you should read the documentation which talks about the possibilities of it timing out.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Ok so `WriteAll` will simply call `Write` with same parameters, and no need for looping

Comment: Why would you provide a `WriteAll` method at all in that case? There's no benefit.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes, true, so I will just use ordinary `Write`. Just to have consistent interface; btw do you know what is DTR, CTS, RTS and if they are used in SerialPort class?

Comment: @JonSkeet I want to be able to enable disable: DTR, RTS, CTS, DSR  XonnXoff - these parameters for serial ports. and can't find if all of them are available for serial port. My C code is doing this and i need similar approach here

Comment: Well that's way beyond the scope of this question...

Comment: @JonSkeet: ok seems I will need to do some research and ask another question if I am stuck(which I seem to be)